Why does ApolloClient InMemoryCache entityStore getFieldValue need to use maybeDeepFreeze?
I'm currently using Apollo Client v3.8.6 in dev mode. I've noticed that when I query a large amount of data (around 6000 objects), it takes approximately 300ms on an M2 MacBook and 800ms on an iPhone 11. After a thorough investigation, I found that a significant portion of the time is spent on the InMemoryCache entityStore's getFieldValue, primarily due to the maybeDeepFreeze function. The deepFreeze function consumes a lot of time. I would like to understand why dev mode requires deepFreeze in getFieldValue.
I expect that in dev mode, the query speed should be as fast as in production mode.

In dev mode, many libraries add additional security checks that catch bugs early - even if they make the library a bit slower.
In this case, it is deep-freezing your query results so you can be warned early if you accidentally modify those query results, which would cause bugs in your app down the line.
Just as an example, if you did something like
const { data } = useQuery(/*...*/)
const sorted = data.items.sort()

You would accidentally be mutating the query result, as .sort doesn't return a modified copy, but sorts the original array.
This subtle modfication could cause rendering inconsistencies in React and bugs in your application, so the data is deep-frozen in dev so you are warned about it early in development.

Can I understand it this way: when developing in dev mode, we ensure that the query data won't be mutated, so in production mode, the deepFreeze can be removed?

Yes. Apollo Client has a lot of warnings that are more costly in dev mode so you catch errors early and since those errors are already found in development, we can skip those checks in production and be more performant there.
